# Google sheets formatting percentages wrong

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I hope this isn't something horrible simple I've overlooked.

I have a sheets document which imports data directly from an external source.
The source uploads numbers in a raw format such as 32.6, when I try to format this to a percentage I get 326.000% when I need 32.6%, I can't seem to find a workaround.

There is an index match formula being used to retrieve this number, but I can't see why that would effect formatting.
When I try it in excel I get the same result unless I manually type out the number.

All the best

Luis Santos

Answer (score 2):

Instead of formating **32.6** to %, you could choose formating one of the following :

- **0.326**
- **=32.6/100**
- **32.6%**

It seems that when you want to format in % you have to use a number between 0 and 1, 0 corresponding to 0%, 1 to 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answers the question but from Google Sheets [manual](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?dark=1&sjid=1011700643319447521-EU):

Format > Number > Custom number formatting

- **@%** - as a string this will display 32.6% and 32.6 when editing a cell.
- **##.#"%"** - as a number this will display 32.6% and 3260% when editing a cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Edit`-->`Find and replace` from the top menu and

1. Find: `(\d+.\d+)`
2. Replace with: `$1%`
3. Search: pick your range
4. Search using regular expressions
5. Replace all

[image]

Following that you just press Done

[image]